# Match image size on web app with screen size of android phone

Tags: android

I'm trying to access my phone from a web app. I can cast my phone's screen to web app which sees the phone's screenshot which is updated every few seconds.

I want to access the buttons and other views from web app..for example by passing coordinates of the button in the image of web app and using the coordinates in android device to check if the coordinates match and if they do then click the button.

But the coordinates of the button in image on web app and on the device are different. How can I change the image on web app to match with the phone so that the coordinates are the same.

Comment: Solution 1 : make the screenshot on the web page the exact dimension of the phone (not really great).
Solution 2 : you know your phone dimensions, as well as the size of the screenshot you display. Simply translate the click coordinates back to the phone coordinates with a rule of three

Comment: @NicolasSimon..you mean make web app image dimensions to 1280x720?

Comment: For Solution1 yes, however it won't be a good if you want your solution to be scalable, reachable from different screen sizes etc (imagine streaming a tablet on a small monitor)
Solution 2 is just about "my phone is 1280x720, and I'm displaying a 640x360". So when I click on position (640, 360) I actually want to click at position (1280, 720) on my device.